Istio metrics customization using Telemetry custom resource
In the earlier version of istio we used EnvoyFilter custom resource to add custom tags to the metrics. As part of this we could add several match conditions to map value to an output attribute.
For example in the following EnvoyFilter the output attribute istio_operationId value will be mapped based on several conditions.
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: "vault-ef"
  labels:
    app: vault
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: "vault"
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
      proxy:
        proxyVersion: '1\.15.*'
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "istio.stats"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
        name: istio.attributegen
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/udpa.type.v1.TypedStruct
          type_url: type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.wasm.v3.Wasm
          value:
            config:
              configuration:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.StringValue
                value: |
                  {
                    "attributes": [
                      {
                        "output_attribute": "istio_operationId",
                        "match": [
                            {
                                "value": "/api/v1/{cusID}/decode",
                                "condition": "request.url_path.matches('/api/v1/[[:alnum:]]*/decode')"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "/api/v1/{cusID}/encode",
                                "condition": "request.url_path.matches('/api/v1/[[:alnum:]]*/encode')"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "/api/v1/{cusID}/tokens/{keyName}/import",
                                "condition": "request.url_path.matches('/api/v1/[[:alnum:]]*/tokens/[[:alnum:]]*/import')"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "/api/v1/{cusID}/tokens/{keyName}/revolve",
                                "condition": "request.url_path.matches('/api/v1/[[:alnum:]]*/tokens/[[:alnum:]]*/revolve')"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "probes",
                                "condition": "request.url_path == '/ready'"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "probes",
                                "condition": "request.url_path == '/live'"
                            },
                        ]
                      },
                    ]
                  }
              vm_config:
                runtime: envoy.wasm.runtime.null
                code:
                  local: { inline_string: "envoy.wasm.attributegen" }

How can the same be achieved using the latest Telemetry resource suggested by istio in the latest versions.
Is below example the right way of achieving the same? Will this have any performance implications?
Please suggest.
apiVersion: telemetry.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Telemetry
metadata:
  name: vault-telemetry
spec:
  metrics:
    - overrides:
      - match:
          metric: ALL_METRICS
          mode: SERVER
        tagOverrides:
          method:
            value: request.method
          istio_operationId:
            value: | 
              request.url_path.matches("/api/v1/[[:alnum:]]*/keys/[[:alnum:]]*/import") ? "/api/v1/{cusID}/keys/{keyName}/import" :
              request.url_path.matches("/api/v1/[[:alnum:]]*/keys/[[:alnum:]]*/revolve") ? "/api/v1/{cusID}/keys/{keyName}/revolve" :
              request.url_path.matches("/api/v1/[[:alnum:]]*/encode") ? "/api/v1/{cusID}/encode" :
              request.url_path.matches("/api/v1/[[:alnum:]]*/decode") ? "/api/v1/{cusID}/decode" :
              request.url_path.matches("/ready") ? "probes" :
              request.url_path.matches("/live") ? "probes" :
              "unknown"
      providers:
        - name: prometheus
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vault


Your path is correct. In newer versions, the Envoy Filter method is advised to be replaced with the Telemetry resource with tag overrides for modifying istio metrics.
Yes, a good approach to do the same functionality is with your Telemetry resource example.Based on URL path matches, it defines metric overrides with tag modifications for the istio_operationID tag.

Because more processing is required to evaluate the expression within value for each tag override, there may be some performance overhead as compared to Envoy Filter.
